# call a function when the value of variable is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on react project. I have used videojs player and I am getting the current time of video and I am storing it in a variable "currentTime". Now I have an array of json, each of which has fields startTime and endTime. As the video progresses, I want to check whether my currentTime lies between startTime or endTime of any of the json which are in array. So I want to make a check function for that. As the currentTime changes continuously, I have set an interval of 500 milisec to compare the currentTime with startTime and endTime. Now if say for some "i" (which is some json inside array) the condition of lying in between gets satisfied, I want to store that "i" in my action reducer. As for some time (startTime - endTime) the value of "i" will remain same, I want to call my action creator just one to store this value of "i", and not for the whole time (startTime-endTime).

I have a function which runs on the interval of 500 ms like this

```
setInterval(function () {
    that.state.tags.map((item, i) => {
        if( item.time <= currentTime && currentTime <= item.stopTime){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }) , 500
})
```

Now the variable `i` remains same for sometime (say 5 secs) when the condition gets satisfied for particular `currentTime`. I have a Redux action creator which should get triggered every time the value of `i` is changed. Since the value of `i` gets stored every 500 milliseconds, I cannot call the action creator every 500ms, that too the same value of `i`. I want to notify or call the action creator when the value of variable `i` changes. How can I do it? I tried this (below), but this what I mentioned that I don't want to do. `markerReachedAction` is the action creator I want to call.

```
setInterval(function () {
    that.state.tags.map((item, i) => {
        if( item.time <= currentTime && currentTime <= item.stopTime){
            that.props.markerReachedAction(i);
            console.log(i);
        }
    }) , 500
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that's about as clear as mud. :-) Not least because `i` is the index of an entry in `that.state.tags` and changes every time `map` calls it (for each array entry).

Comment: You should almost certainly not be using `setInterval` for this. If you want to react to state changes you should use the built-in [`componentWillUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) or [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle hook, which will be called every time your component's props or state change (before and after rendering, respectively), whereupon you can check if the particular values you're interested in have changed.

Comment: @Jordan I have to use setInterval because I want to compare the currentTime in every very small interval as the currentTime is the time videojs player which changes continuously.

Comment: I don't see why you have to use `setInterval` in order to do that.

Comment: @Jordan What should I do then? Can you please guide?

Comment: @Jordan please have a look at the update in questions's explaination which will help you to understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Where is the code that sets `currentTime`? Also, JSON is a data serialization format, much like CSV, YAML or XML. To say that you have an "array of JSON" is incorrect. If you receive JSON data from e.g. an ajax call and then deserialize it with e.g. `JSON.parse`, you no longer have JSON. What you have is an array of JavaScript objects. The terms are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** you're saying you want to call `that.props.markerReachedAction` every time the entry in `that.state.tags` where `item.time <= currentTime && currentTime <= item.stopTime` *changes* (e.g., time has moved on, and now instead of entry 0 matching, it's entry 1).

If so, [as Jordan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253209/call-a-function-when-the-value-of-variable-is-changed/42253405#comment71665486_42253209), `setInterval` is probably not the right tool. But without more context, it's hard to point you in the right direction.

In terms of getting it working with `setInterval`, you need to remember the last value of the matching index. Also, `map` is the wrong tool to use to just loop through an array (it builds a new array). To just loop, use `forEach`; but in your case, you want to *stop* looping when the condition is reached. Normally, that would be `some` (just generally stopping when you reach a condition), `find` (finding a specific entry in the array based on callback), or `findIndex` (finding the *index* of a specific entry in the array based on a callback). In your case, `findIndex`:

```
let lastNotifiedIndex = -1; // -1 won't match any array index, so we'll fire the first time
setInterval(function() {
    // Find the index for which our predicate function returns true
    const index = that.state.tags.findIndex(item => item.time <= currentTime && currentTime <= item.stopTime);

    // If we found one, is it different?
    if (index !== -1 && lastNotifiedIndex !== index) {
        // Yes, notify
        lastNotifiedIndex = index;
        that.props.markerReachedAction(lastNotifiedIndex);
    }
}, 500);
```

I assume something, somewhere, is updating `currentTime`? If not, you probably want to update it at the beginning of the timer callback.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Could you use `Array.prototype.findIndex` instead of `Array.prototype.some` here?

Comment: @Jordan: Doh! Yes, of course you could. I started to use `find` (not `findIndex`) then realized that I wanted the index instead of the entry...and then apparently lost the plot. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @ApurvG: See Jordan's comment above and the updated answer. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have updated the ques for more insights on what exactly I am trying to do

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to set the value of lastNotifiedIndex to -1 when the currentTime doesn't lie between any of the startTime and endTime. Can you please add that piece also in your code. I am not able figure out the way. Would be a big help.

Comment: @ApurvG: That's exactly what `findIndex` returns if none of the entries matches.

Comment: No once it matches, it stays to that value until the next value matches. What I want is once a range (startTime to endTime of a paricular array item) ends, I should get -1 until the next range comes.

Comment: @ApurvG: That's exactly what happens with the above: If none of the items matches, `findIndex` returns -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135834/discussion-between-apurvg-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please help me out here